# SSIS 2008 pb with file system task to delete a file

Tags: ssis

in my foreach loop container, I would like to delete the current processed file.
I try as follows, but no file is deleted at the end, any idea??

[image]

Here is the property of my loop , Current processed file comes from **FileNameSimu** variable
[image: Here is the property of my loop]

I would like to delete the current file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the value in the variable `User::FileNameSimu` contains the file path like `C:\Folder1\SubFolder2\File.txt` and not just the file name `File.txt`

Please note the description of the property SourceVariable on File System Task. It expects a path.

[image: File System Path]

On the *Variables* window, select the variable **FilePath** and press *F4* to view the properties of the variable. Change the property **EvaluateAsExpression** to `True` and set the value `@[User::Directory] +  @[User::FileName]` to the property **Expression** assuming that your variable Directory contains the folder path and the variable FileName contains the name. Make sure that the variable Directory ends with a backslash at the end like `C:\temp\` and not like `C:\temp`. If it doesn't have a backslash at the end change your expression to `@[User::Directory] + "\\" + @[User::FileName]`

[image: Variable]

**Or use the backslash in the expression**

[image: Variable with backslash]

Comment: thanks for the remark, you're right, my variable is only a file name.. However I have another variable which contain the path of the directory, how can I easily create a new variable Path_FileName_toDel = @[DIR]+@[FileName] ?